# MySQL Error 1452 when inserting data

Tags: mysql, sa-mp

I keep getting errors when importing my old SQL file and fix them all,but I'm stuck and can't understand what this means.

> ALTER TABLE `property`   ADD CONSTRAINT `property_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`intid`) REFERENCES `interiors` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE
>   CASCADE,   ADD CONSTRAINT `property_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`owner`)
>   REFERENCES `accounts` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
>   MySQL said: Documentation
>
> 1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`ionicnew`.`#sql-252c_e1`, CONSTRAINT `property_ibfk_2` FOREIGN
>   KEY (`owner`) REFERENCES `accounts` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON
>   UPDATE CASCADE)

Full code of `property` table:

```
CREATE TABLE `property` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `x` float NOT NULL,
  `y` float NOT NULL,
  `z` float NOT NULL,
  `a` float NOT NULL,
  `type` bit(32) NOT NULL,
  `intid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `price` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `mapicon` tinyint(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `point` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `saleprice` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `owner` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `money` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `level` tinyint(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

ALTER TABLE `property`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `intid` (`intid`),
  ADD KEY `owner` (`owner`);

ALTER TABLE `property`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=86;

ALTER TABLE `property`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `property_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`intid`) REFERENCES `interiors` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `property_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`owner`) REFERENCES `accounts` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

I can upload the full SQL file if needed.

Comment: Can you add table description for `interiors` and `accounts`

Comment: We need to see the data in `property` and the other two referring tables, `interiors` and `accounts`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Foreign key relationships involve a parent table that holds the
>   central data values, and a child table with identical values pointing
>   back to its parent. The FOREIGN KEY clause is specified in the child
>   table.
>
> It will reject any INSERT or UPDATE operation that attempts to create
>   a foreign key value in a child table if there is no a matching
>   candidate key value in the parent table.
>
> **To know more Go to this [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)**

So your error `Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails` essentially means that, you are trying to add a row to your `property` table for which no matching row `(intid)` is present in `interiors` table.

You must first insert the row to your `interiors` table.

Comment: Thanks!
I solved my problem by disable the foreign key checks in import page though.

Comment: Welcome!! @Fair